# Remove the image/icon space in XUL menuitem and vertcal line in menupopup

Tags: css, firefox-addon, xul

[image]

I have a `menupopup` which when used on Windows 7 in Firefox 6.0.2 shows some space on the left. But when used with Firefox 4 and Windows XP does not show space on the left. How can I remove the space on the left?

```xml
<toolbarbutton id="search" type="menu" label="SEARCH" width="83" height="25" oncommand="webSearch();event.stopPropagation();">              
    <menupopup>
        <menuitem label="Web" value="webs" oncommand="webSearch();event.stopPropagation();" />
        <menuitem label="Images" value="images" oncommand="imageSearch();event.stopPropagation();"/>
        <menuitem label="News" value="news" oncommand="newsSearch();event.stopPropagation();" />
        <menuitem label="Video" value="videos" oncommand="videoSearch();event.stopPropagation();"/>
    </menupopup>
</toolbarbutton>
```

The `menuitem` should be in the center of the popup. Also, there is a thin line before the displayed `label` (check the above screenshot). I want to remove that line.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
        <window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
        <row>
        <toolbarbutton id="search" type="menu" label="SEARCH" width="83" height="25" oncommand="webSearch();event.stopPropagation();">             
                <menupopup id="editItems" position="after_pointer">
                    <menuitem label="Web" value="webs" oncommand="webSearch();event.stopPropagation();" />
                    <menuitem label="Images" value="images" oncommand="imageSearch();event.stopPropagation();"/>
                    <menuitem label="News" value="news" oncommand="newsSearch();event.stopPropagation();" />
                    <menuitem label="Video" value="videos" oncommand="videoSearch();event.stopPropagation();"/>
                  </menupopup>
        </toolbarbutton>
        </row>
        </window>
```

As per the documentation you can't position at the center but I would you to use your toolbar button inside a row then use any one of positioning attributes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/PopupGuide/Positioning
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menupopup
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/images,_tables,_and_mysterious_gaps

Please refer to these links for further information.

Comment: i think i m not able to explain my problem to u. the problem in not the popup positioning. just check out the popup menu for the firefox 6. their is a thin line before the keyword. check the file popup. i want to remove that line.

Comment: @gargi: would you mind posting the screenshot of the problem with the thin line. I used your code in my system with FF version 6 I don't see any thin line.

Comment: Actually as far as i know. it is property of firefox6 and its used to display images for the menuitems as this type of line can be seen in every popup of the firefox6. just check when u right click the same type of popup appears an also check the file menu , same type of thing is coming so i think its not possible to remove it.

Comment: Nope, if you use CSS program please check with that. As i said yesterday I don't see any thin line in my system with FF V6.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the [`<menuitem>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/menuitem) elements will display with space for icons on the left of the [`<menupopup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/menupopup):

[image: Default <code><menuitems></code>]

You can have the `<menuitem>` elements display without the space for icons by adding [`class="menuitem-non-iconic"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/menuitem#Style_classes) to each element:

[image: <code><menuitems></code> without space for icons, but with vertical line]

However, if you look closely, there is a vertical line down the menu. You can remove this vertical line by changing the `<menupopup>` element to have the style `-moz-appearance: none;`.  This can be done either in a CSS file, or as `style` attribute, `style="-moz-appearance: none;"`, on the element:

[image: <code><menuitems></code> without space for icons, but without vertical line]

Putting those together the basic code looks like:

```
<toolbarbutton id="search" type="menu" label="SEARCH">
    <menupopup style="-moz-appearance: none;">
        <menuitem class="menuitem-non-iconic" label="Web"/>
        <menuitem class="menuitem-non-iconic" label="Images"/>
        <menuitem class="menuitem-non-iconic" label="News"/>
        <menuitem class="menuitem-non-iconic" label="Video"/>
    </menupopup>
</toolbarbutton>
```

Using your complete code:

```
<toolbarbutton id="search" type="menu" label="SEARCH" width="83" height="25" oncommand="webSearch();event.stopPropagation();">
    <menupopup style="-moz-appearance: none;">
        <menuitem class="menuitem-non-iconic" label="Web" value="webs" oncommand="webSearch();event.stopPropagation();" />
        <menuitem class="menuitem-non-iconic" label="Images" value="images" oncommand="imageSearch();event.stopPropagation();"/>
        <menuitem class="menuitem-non-iconic" label="News" value="news" oncommand="newsSearch();event.stopPropagation();" />
        <menuitem class="menuitem-non-iconic" label="Video" value="videos" oncommand="videoSearch();event.stopPropagation();"/>
    </menupopup>
</toolbarbutton>
```

**Centering the text:**
One interpretation of your last statement of "The `menuitem` should be in the center of the popup", is that you want the `<menuitem>` text centered horizontally in the popup. I don't think this is really what you intended. But, in case it was what you desired: you can center the text by indicating the `text-align: center;` style either via the `style` attribute or CSS:

```
<toolbarbutton id="search" type="menu" label="SEARCH">
    <menupopup style="-moz-appearance: none;">
        <menuitem class="menuitem-non-iconic" style="text-align: center;" label="Web"/>
        <menuitem class="menuitem-non-iconic" style="text-align: center;" label="Images"/>
        <menuitem class="menuitem-non-iconic" style="text-align: center;" label="News"/>
        <menuitem class="menuitem-non-iconic" style="text-align: center;" label="Video"/>
    </menupopup>
</toolbarbutton>
```

This results in:

[image: Popup with centered text]

Comment: Used this also for a sub menu on a statusbarpanel.  Wherever the menupopup/menuitems live, this technique ought to work correctly.